# PTP/IP access to iPhone?

Tags: ios, applications, network

Is there a way (aka an app) to provide PTP/IP access to an iPhone?

Googling has only given me hits on accessing a PTP/IP camera *from* iOS, or turning an iDevice into an IP (security) cam.

Comment: Is jailbreaking an option for you?

Comment: I have no a-prioris against it (already tried it with the iPhone 4S that became basically unusable under the newest supported OS). Here it's about an iPhone SE (1st Gen) which apparently no longer gets even security updates (but which does need to remain secure enough for banking apps and the like).
Are you saying there's no app that does this, while there are apps that expose the photo library via a webserver?